# change layout of the activity at run time in android

Tags: android, android-activity

i am developing one android application,there i need to change layout of activity at run time

i want to know about ,how to change a layout of an activity as view mode change from portrait to landscape or  visa-verse

please anyone tell me what is feasible and efficient solution for above problem.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach is to have a folder for landscape orientation also, you will name it like

```
layout-land
```

you will put another `main.xml` inside that folder, android framework will automatically select that layout for landscape orientation.

More info here from android guide for [supporting multiple screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

Answer (score 1):

Code for detecting orientation change

```
 @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            if(newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
                SharedVariables.isScreenOrientPotrail=false;
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

            }
            else if(newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES){
                SharedVariables.isScreenOrientPotrail=true;
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dyanmic_layoutid, null, true);
```

add **rowview** to your mainlayout.

Answer (score 0):

i am pasting code here..try this..

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration orient) 
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(orient);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (orient.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
                      //code here for LANDSCAPE..
        ));   

        }
        else if (orient.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {           
                      //code here for PORTRAIT ..   
            }               
    }
```

CAll Method;

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        onConfigurationChanged(getResources().getConfiguration());
    }
```